# Should I change the engine oil on a boat engine after it sat for 5 months?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, oil, boat

I have a Reinell Bowrider, with a 190 HP Chevy engine, that hasn't been started in about 5 months.

Before starting it, should I change the engine oil? Or will it run okay without changing it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the oil is concerned, you should be okay. Check oil level and start it.

Other issues may arise with a boat engine (likely with a carburetor) that's been sitting around for 5 months, for example rough idle, etc.